# Why has the meta user option been removed from my profile?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, profile-page

I'm not  able to  find the  meta  user option on my profile:

[image]

I have to type **math.meta.stackexchange.com**  on Google   to visit this site.

Comment: It's under "profile" on the top right

Comment: There's also a shortcut under your "list of all StackExchange sites" icon at upper right (works on both profile and activity tabs), and on the profile page at left under **Top Meta Posts** there is a *View meta profile* link.

Comment: @jasmine just a suggestion please always have a small check check on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) before asking a question on Math Meta because maximum of your question can be found in MSE (Meta StackExchange).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @ArcticChar notes in the comments, it's under the profile button/dropdown:

[image]

This is a recent change: [We’ve shipped some changes to the user profile navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369276/295232) and this feature isn't even properly mentioned, but the responsible developer commented about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368661/additional-profile-refinements#comment1229829_368661):

> Oooh, sorry it's not in the demo @Glorfindel. It shows you your Teams profiles, network profile, and meta / main site links. If there's just the one link, I plan on showing just that link with no dropdown.

All users have a network profile, so it's almost always a dropdown (it *is* possible to have a main site account without a meta account).

Answer (score 9):

I have never accessed Meta through my profile. Here is another way: click on the rightmost icon on the top bar of the site, where you have all your other communities, *and* Meta.

[image]